# heroku-buildpack-apt; Unable to locate package

Tags: heroku, apt

I am using the buildpack located at https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt.git to install required packages using the Aptfile. Everything worked fine for a while, but now every package gives an "Unable to locate package" error. This is with the exact same files on the exact same heroku stack. Did the buildpack for using Aptfile deprecate or is there a workaround?

Full build log:

````
-----> Using buildpacks:
       1. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt.git
       2. heroku/python
       3. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python.git
       4. https://github.com/matt-bertoncello/python-pyodbc-buildpack.git
-----> Apt app detected
-----> Detected Aptfile or Stack changes, flushing cache
-----> Updating apt caches
       Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease [265 kB]
       Get:2 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg InRelease [81.6 kB]
       Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [109 kB]
       Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
       Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages [1,275 kB]
       Get:6 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg/main amd64 Packages [311 kB]
       Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages [11.3 MB]
       Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages [786 kB]
       Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages [699 kB]
       Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [1,203 kB]
       Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [965 kB]
       Fetched 17.2 MB in 2s (7,544 kB/s)
       Reading package lists...
-----> Fetching .debs for unixodbc
       Reading package lists...
       Building dependency tree...
E: Unable to locate package unixodbc
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Apt app.
 !     Push failed```
````